# Using iCloud in iOS app extension

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ios-app-extension

I'm writing an iMessage extension and encountered a problem when trying to upload data using CloudKit.

When I try to upload data from within the container application, everything works fine, but when I'm running the same code in the extension I get the following exception:

```
'CKException', reason: 'The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services'
```

Is there a way to set entitlements for the app extension or is not being apple to connect to iCloud from an extension deliberate design choice?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, I'm being stupid. I forgot to enable iCloud capability for BOTH the container app AND the extension target. Then, I needed to specify the same iCloud container for both targets. Works like a charm.